# Component setSize method in FlowLayout object

Tags: java, swing, components, flowlayout, preferredsize

I'm currently making a GUI that makes use of the FlowLayout class. Now, this class is meant to allow components be set by their prefer sized methods and I believe, isn't supposed to have priority in setting the component size. However, when I used a setSize method for a JTextField, the FlowLayout object didn't seem to recognize the change size command. But when I used the setColumn method, the FlowLayout object did respond to the change in size command.

Why is this?

Comment: *"..by their prefer sized methods and I believe, isn't supposed to have priority in setting the component size. However, when I used a setSize method.."*  The preferred size and size are different things.  But avoid both of them.  See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  for the reasons why.

Answer (score 1):

> FlowLayout object didn't seem to recognize the change size command.
>   But when I used the setColumn method, the FlowLayout object did
>   respond to the change in size command. **Why is this?**

Form your own question i understand that you know `FlowLayout` works obeying component's preferred size. However to answer your question why really `JTextFeild.setColumn(int)` responds: **Because**,

As soon as `setColumn(int)` is called, it invalidate() the `JTextFeild` component and and all parents above it to be marked as *needing to be laid out*.

```
public void setColumns(int columns) {
        int oldVal = this.columns;
        if (columns < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("columns less than zero.");
        }
        if (columns != oldVal) {
            this.columns = columns;
            invalidate(); // invalidate if column changes
        }
    }
```

Then while laying out, FlowLayout calls the  `getPreferredSize()` function of JTextFeild, which is overridden and implemented such that it returns the preferred width by adding  the column width:

```
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension size = super.getPreferredSize();
        if (columns != 0) {
            Insets insets = getInsets();
            size.width = columns * getColumnWidth() +
                insets.left + insets.right;  // changing the width
        }
        return size;
    }
```

Guess what! I am becoming fan of source code.